# Помогите разобраться с передачей значения из js в html и обратно

Tags: javascript, html

Код:

```
numbers:<input id="numbers">
<br>
<button id="qqq">Search</button>
<hr>
<p id="min">min:</p>

<script>
  var inputElements = document.getElementById('numbers').value;
  var min ;
  //var nnn = 1000;

  document.getElementById('min').innerHTML += inputElements; //если вместо inputElements написать nnn, то выведет 1000(значение nnn)
  var inputElementsArray = inputElements.split(' ');
  document.getElementById('qqq').alert(Math.max(inputElementsArray);
</script>
```

Скажу сразу, что я пересмотрел  вопросы  по  поводу передачи данных html -> js -> html , вот написал код ....но не пойму что не так?

П.С.:переменной inputElements  присваиваем значение, которое было введено в поле input (строку разбили на массив), а потом нажимаем на кнопку и в указанном поле должно вывести максимальное число элемента массива,но не выводит.... (если вместо inputElements написать nnn, то выведет 1000(значение nnn))

Comment: `document.getElementById('qqq').alert(Math.max(inputElementsArray);` - это неверная конструкция, у элемента нет метода `alert`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. вам нужно получать значения при клике на кнопку, а не при загрузке скрипта;
2. вы не повешали обработчик события по нажатию на кнопку;
3. при "разрезании" строки `.split()` возвращается массив строк, которые вам надо конвертировать в число каждый (нам помогает `.map()` для перебора массива и `+` для конвертации строки в число);
4. `Math.min()` не может получать массив чисел. Можно воспользоваться `Math.min.apply(null, array)`;
5. и в конце просто присвоить элементу значение через `.innerHTML = value`.

```js
document.getElementById('qqq').onclick = function() {
  var numbers = document
    .getElementById('numbers')
    .value
    .split(' ');
  document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = Math.min.apply(null, numbers);
}
```

```html
numbers:<input id="numbers">
<br>
<button id="qqq">Search</button>
<hr>
<p id="min">min:</p>
```

Или используя `ES6`:

```js
document.getElementById('qqq').onclick = () => {
  var numbers = document
    .getElementById('numbers')
    .value
    .split(' ');
  document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = Math.min(...numbers);
};
```

```html
numbers:<input id="numbers">
<br>
<button id="qqq">Search</button>
<hr>
<p id="min">min:</p>
```

Comment: про + даже не знал, отличный опыт! Math.min() не может получать массив чисел - может, через деструктивное присваивание.

Comment: _Или используя ES6_ - Тогда уж и `Math.min.apply` надо было заменить на `spread operator`: `Math.min(...numbers)`. Кстати, `.map(val => +val)` делать не обязательно, аргументы `Math.min` и так будут приведены к числу

Answer (score 4):

И мой вариант ответа:

```js
let numbers = document.getElementById('numbers');
let search = document.getElementById('qqq');
let result = document.getElementById('min');

search.addEventListener('click', function() {
 let arr = numbers.value.split(' ').map(el=> {
  return Number(el);
 }) 
 result.innerText = Math.max(...arr)
})
```

```html
numbers:<input id="numbers" type="text" value="10 20 50 5">
<br>
<button id="qqq">Search</button>
<hr>
max:<p id="min"></p>
```

Comment: Красивое решение передачи массива в `.min()`. Не слышал о таких, круто :)

Comment: К слову, если вы пользуетесь `ES6`, то `el => { return Number(el); }` можно сократить как `el => Number(el)`

Comment: не могу, из-за того же деструктивного присваивания. Если не возвращать значение не сработает. Или я чего-то не понимаю еще...

Comment: посмотрите мой ответ внизу, я обновился